# Как запустить фрагмент сразу при запуске?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте. У меня есть NavDrawer, в нём есть пункт "расписание". Мне надо сделать так, чтобы при запуске моего приложения сразу открывался фрагмент "расписание", а не оставалось пустое место. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Запускаем фрагмент и выделяем пункт меню в драйвере

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
 navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nameItem); // выделяем пункт в драйвере
```

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.контейнер_для_фрагмента, МойФрагмент).commit(); я правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

Создаётся поле:

```
private Fragment fragment = null;
```

В метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` вашей activity добавляем следующее:

```
fragment = new FragmentHome();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Вместо `new FragmentHome()` пишем `new Имя_фрагмента()` соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы показываете/добавляете/меняете фрагменты по нажатию на пункт в `NavigationView` то у вас должен быть обработчик нажатий на оный, в котором, в зависимости от ID нажатого элемента у вас происходит работа с фрагментами.

Если всё вышеизложенное верно, то вам надо программно нажать на пункт в списке. Если же сам обработчик нажатий реализован прямо в активити/фрагменте, то вы можете просто вызвать этот метод, передав туда нужный ID

Comment: Здравствуйте. А как программно нажать на пункт?

Comment: @МихаилПушкарёв, ну, по идее просто взять слушатель нажатий и вызвать метод-обработчик

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от выбраного пункта загружайте свой фрагмент.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_week) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Navigation Week");
            fragment = FragmentWeatherMain.newInstance();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_today) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Navigation today");
            fragment = FragmentCurrentWeather.newInstance();
         }
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
     return true;
    }
```

Comment: Нет, мне то надо сразу при открытии